# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2MCREF~E.JPG'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to open an image that resides at a different location than my script

Code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

folder = '/Users/abc'
if not os.listdir(folder):
    print('Folder not found')
else:
    print('"{}" found'.format(folder))

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    print(file)
    data = Image.open(file,'r')
print('Done')
```

Error:

```
"/Users/abc" found
2MCREF~E.JPG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img_to_s3bucket.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = Image.open(file,'r')
  File "/Users/AjayB/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2770, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2MCREF~E.JPG'
```

How to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be **because your working directory and the location of the file are not same**.

You could do this by specifying the full file path in the below command:

```
data = Image.open(file,'r')
```

you can do this by:

```
data = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, file),'r'))
```